# has good reason vs has a good reason

Tags: uncountable-nouns

1. Tom has good reason to be angry.
2. Tom may well be angry.

My textbook says that the above two sentences are the same. What is the meaning of "reason" above?

Comment: Your textbook may be poor quality. 'Tom has good reason to be angry' and 'Tom may well be angry' do not mean the same thing.

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey Do you imply that 'a' is missing from 1.?

Comment: No, I mean that 'may well' does not only mean what your book says.

Comment: "Has **a** good reason" means that he has one specific reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Reason' used as a mass (non-count) noun can mean justification, or good and obvious cause to do or feel something. 'Good' may precede the noun to strengthen the statement.

> Reason
>
> 1.1 mass noun
> Good or obvious cause to do something.
> *we have [good] reason to celebrate

[Reason (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/definition/reason)

'May well be' usually means 'is very probably'. The 'has good reason to be' meaning is, perhaps, a little -old-fashioned. One may see an inversion: 'Well may he be angry', which avoids the ambiguity.

Comment: 'Rare and archaic'?? [This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+good+reason+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chas%20good%20reason%20to%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chas%20good%20reason%20to%3B%2Cc0) shows that its use has declined since the late 19th century, but it's still going strong.

Comment: @KateBunting - do you agree with my edit? - Mike

Comment: OK, thanks. (I certainly use it, but I suppose I'm 'a little old-fashioned'!)

Comment: @KateBunting - I don't know if I count as 'old-fashioned', but I am aware of, and often employ, usages that were coined before about 2010 AD.

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey So does "well may one do" means it is natural for one to do something?

Comment: In the context of ***having [a] good reason to** [say, do, or think something]*, including the article has [only recently](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+good+reason+to%2Chave+a+good+reason+to&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) started to become more common (more common that it ***was***; it's always been and remains much less common than ***not*** including the article).